# Optimal control- Chain problem differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization

I'm trying to solve the following exercise:
Find the minimum of 
$$J(x)=\int_{t_0}^{t_f} x(t)(1+\dot x(t)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} \,dt $$ 
if $x(t_0)=x_0,x(t_f)=x_f$ and the length of the curve satisfies this equation
$$ \int_{t_0}^{t_f}(1+\dot x(t)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} \, dt =\ell$$

My work so far is (using Lagrange multipliers:
I defined the functional 
    $$F_a(t,(x,z),(\dot x,\dot z),p)=x(1+\dot x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}+p[\dot z - (1 + \dot x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}] $$

where
$$z(t)=\int_{t_0}^t (1+\dot x(t)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} \, dt, z(t_0)=0, z(t_f) = \ell.$$
So we have:
$$\frac{\partial F_a}{\partial x}-\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial F_a}{\partial \dot x}=0 \Leftrightarrow (1+\dot x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}=0 \tag 1 $$
$$\frac{\partial F_a}{\partial z}-\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial F_a}{\partial \dot z}=0 \Leftrightarrow \dot p =0 \tag 2$$
$$\frac{\partial F_a}{\partial p}-\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial F_a}{\partial \dot p}=0 \Leftrightarrow \dot z =(1+\dot x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} \tag 3$$
How should I proceed from here on??